# How to make some action by clicking on Enter button in java?

Tags: java, swing

When i make `KeyboardFocusManager` to make some actions by clicking on Enter it works but it does this actions two times ,so i don't why this happen.

And this is my code

```
       KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (ZE.isVisible() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                edafet_3ameel();
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the method which i use to do the actions

```
    public void edafet_3ameel() {

    String sql = "insert into omalaa (Zesm_3ameel , Zrased ) values (?,?)";

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        statement.setString(1, esm_3ameelZE_txt.getText());
        statement.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(rasedZE_txt.getText()));

        statement.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "تم بنجاح", "تم",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

And this is a minimal code of my gui

```
    ZE = new JPanel();
    boo.adapt_panel(ZE, non, frame, 0, 0, 1366, 768, Color.WHITE, "no");

    topZE = new JPanel();
    boo.adapt_panel(topZE, ZE, frame, 0, 0, 1366, 80, Color.decode("#3b69a6"), "no");

    backZE = new JButton();
    backZE.setBorder(null);
    boo.adapt_button(backZE, topZE, 39, 13, 59, 59, "image", "back.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 21, "yes", "yes");

    homeZE = new JButton();
    homeZE.setBorder(null);
    boo.adapt_button(homeZE, topZE, 113, 13, 59, 59, "image", "home.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 21, "yes", "yes");

    tamZE = new JButton();
    boo.adapt_button(tamZE, ZE, 10, 699, 100, 59, "image", "tam.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 21, "yes", "yes");

    esm_3ameelZE = new JLabel();
    boo.adapt_label(esm_3ameelZE, ZE, 1149, dy[0], 200, 34, "image", "esm 3ameel.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 10, "no", "yes");

    rasedZE = new JLabel();
    boo.adapt_label(rasedZE, ZE, 1149, dy[1], 200, 34, "image", "rased.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 10, "no", "yes");

    titleZE = new JLabel();
    boo.adapt_label(titleZE, topZE, 897, 0, 469, 80, "image", "edafet 3ameel top.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 10, "no", "yes");

    program_sign = new JLabel();
    boo.adapt_label(program_sign, topZE, 450, 0, 361, 78, "image", "program sign.png", "serif", Font.PLAIN, 10, "yes", "yes");

    esm_3ameelZE_txt = new JTextField();
    boo.adapt_textField(esm_3ameelZE_txt, ZE, 940, dy[0], 255, 34, "", "sanserif", Font.PLAIN, 21, "yes", "yes");

    rasedZE_txt = new JTextField();
    boo.adapt_textField(rasedZE_txt, ZE, 940, dy[1], 255, 34, "", "sanserif", Font.PLAIN, 21, "yes", "yes");
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal code of the GUI, please?

Comment: In my experience with detecting key events, holding the key for a given amount of time can cause multiple keyEvents to take place. If you hold down the key, does the action take place more than two times?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo i edited my post and wrote a minimal code of my GUI

Comment: @S.McConnell yes, the action take place more than two times

Comment: Try applying the fix described here and see if that fixes it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678173/how-do-i-the-keyevent-only-once-when-it-is-held-down

Answer (score 1):

There are typically multiple key events when you physically press on a key. Such as: key pressed, key released etc... Can you specify that the event occurs when the key is pressed and not just any event associated with the enter key?

Comment: The event occurs two times when i press the enter key only which i specified in if statement and there's no any other key make the event occurs

Comment: But what I am saying is that pressing the enter key causes two key events (keyPressed, keyReleased). Check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

"Pressing and releasing a key on the keyboard results in the generating the following key events (in order): 
    KEY_PRESSED
    KEY_TYPED (is only generated if a valid Unicode character could be generated.)
    KEY_RELEASED
 "

In your code you aren't distinguishing these key events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute always to must introducing a variable for in your KeyboardFocusManager, the code is simple to this

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            private boolean press = true;

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (panelOne.isVisible() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && !press)
                {
                    System.out.println("I pressed Enter with another method");
                    press = true;
                    return press;
                }
                press = false;
                return press;
            }
        });
```

The output at the click is this

```
I pressed Enter with another method
```

if you want to execute only when the JPanel is selected you can try this solution

```
int c = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
panelOne.getInputMap(c).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "enter");
panelOne.getActionMap().put("enter", new AbstractAction() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("I pressed Enter on JPANEL when is selected");
   }
});
```

This is the reference for the second [solution](https://coderanch.com/t/346419/java/Action-Listener-Enter-Key-pressing)